# Django get foreign key objects

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am coming from .NET Core and I am curious if Django has anything similar to .NET Core's projections.  For instance, I can describe a relationship in a .NET Core model and then later query for it.  So, if `Articles` can have an `Author` I can do something like:

`var articles = dbContext.Where(article.ID == id).Inclue(a => a.author);`

What I would get back are articles that have their author attached.

Is there anything similar to this in Django?  How can I load related data in Django that's described in the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The query you wrote is more or less equivalent to:

```
Article.objects.filter(id=some_id).prefetch_related('author')
```

or:

```
Article.objects.filter(id=some_id).select_related('author')
```

## `select_related` versus `prefetch_related`

in case the number of `Author`s is limited, or more a one-to-one relation. In case you pull a large number of `Article`s, and several `Article`s map to the *same* `Author`, it is usually better to use `prefetch_related`: this will first look for the `Author` identifiers, perform a uniquness filter, and then fetch those into memory.

The same holds if multiple `Author`s write one article (so a *one-to-many* or *many-to-many* relation). Since that would mean that if we perform a `JOIN` at the database level, we repeat every article by the number of `Author`s who wrote that article, and we repeat every `Author` by the number of `Article`s they wrote. We usually want to avoid this "multiplicative" behavior for such sets. So in that case `prefetch_related` will have *linear behavior*: first fetching the relevant `Article`s, next fetching the relevant `Author`s.

## Lazy loading of related objects

But you actually do not need to perform a `prefetch_related` for a single instance. In case you load an article, you can simply use `some_article.author`. If the corresponding `Author` instance is not yet loaded, Django will perform an additional query fetching the related `Author` instance.

So Django can load attributes that correspond to related objects in a *lazy* manner: it simply loads the `Article` if you fetch it in memory, and if you later need the `Author`, or the `Journal`, or the `.editor` of the `Journal` (which is for example an `Author` as well), Django will each time make a new query and load related object(s). In case you want however to process a list of `Article`s in batch, `select_related` and `prefect_related` are advisable, since they will result in a limited number of queries to fetch all related objects, instead of one query per related instance.

The lazy loading of related objects can be more efficient if one frequently has to fetch zero or at most a few related instances (for example because it depends on some attributes of the `Article` whether we are really interested in the `Author` after all).

Comment: Hmm, actually neither of these are working for me unfortunately when giving the Django model the `author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Sethen: can you post the full model? Did you make migrations and applied these?

Comment: Here is the full model -- it's a character model that I am trying to match with a game: https://gist.github.com/sethen/4d3f3cd748bb7bfebd20d8ce49785b73

Comment: So you wrote something like `Character.objects.filter(id=123).prefetch_related('game')`? (of course with `123` the real `id`).

Comment: Although not relevant here, you do not have to add an `id = AutoField()` yourself, if no primary key is mentioned, Django generates one automatically.

Comment: It's for the PyLinter, it gets pissed off in that `save` method if it's not explicitly there.

Comment: Yes I did, and all I get back is something like `[{"id": 1, "name": "name", "game": 1}]` where I expect `game` to be filled in with the details.

Comment: Does it show `<QuerySet [...]>` around it? Because then you have an iterable that has the `Character` instances. Then it is only a matter of representation. When I perform the above queries, I get the objects (when I iterate over them), for both queries.

Comment: Yeah it's basically `>>> Character.objects.filter(id=1).prefetch_related('game')
<QuerySet [<Character: Name>]>` ... Do I have to iterate over them?

Comment: Well then you got the `Character` instances, you can now for example write `for char in Character.objects.filter(id=1).prefetch_related('game'): ...` to process each element. In case you want to use only *one* game. You can use `.get(..)` as well (but at the end of the query), to fetch the single instance into memory.

Comment: `>>> Character.objects.prefetch_related('game').get(pk=1)
<Character: Name>` The `get` thing you suggested isn't working.

Comment: Well you get the `Character` now. This is how it is "printed". But this is the character. And you can write `.game` at the end, to see the `Game`. Note that this is only a *textual representation*. Typically Django hides the related objects, in the rendering, since that could result in extra queries.

Comment: I got it -- I was using Django Rest Framework so I had to do it differently, but the idea was the same!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are looking for [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). This traverses FK relationships based on how they are created in your models.